# Can I add custom metrics and dimensions to the web plus app property in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a web property that I could add custom metrics and dimensions to track them on my web app through: Admin --> Property Settings --> custom Definitions

But I created a new web + app property in my Google Analytics and I can't seem to find a way to add custom metrics and dimensions.

Is there any way to add custom metrics and dimensions to web + app properties?

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind, the new web+app properties are in beta, a few people of note in the Analytics and Tag Manager community have made a point of stating this type of property is nowhere yet near close for using in a production environment.

Custom dimensions and metrics do not appear to be available. From the reading I have done so far, I'm guessing they *may* get replaced with Custom Parameter Reporting

> You can also identify up to 100 custom event parameters per project
>   (50 numeric and 50 textual) to include in reporting by registering
>   those parameters with their corresponding events. Once you register
>   your custom parameters, Google Analytics for Firebase displays a
>   corresponding data card in each related event-detail report.

Ref: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&utm_id=ad

I haven't looked into this much in relation to setting it up. However GA does provide space in it's new reports for this type of property in relation to custom parameter reporting. eta.. cant find the documentation i was looking for however i think it is 20 text and 20 numeric for GA standard

[image: GA Parameter Reports Web+App Property]